# Permalinks for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

I have custom post type **tour**.
Also I have custom taxonomy **cattour**

**Tour** and **cattour** are connected

Now I have, for example

```
domain.com/cattour/berlin/ (the result of taxonomy-cattour.php)
```

and I have

```
domain.com/tour/name-of-sightseeing (single-tour.php)
```

But I need to get

```
 domain.com/berlin
```

and

```
domain.com/berlin/name-of-sightseeing
```

Please, help. How can I do it properly?